# Comparable editor for gedit with less dependencies?

Tags: gnome, editors, development

I want to leave Gnome and install awesome on debian squeeze or wheezy, but I really can't work without gedit. Is there any text editor like gedit capable of editing columns, highlighting nearly any language, and building texfiles straight from the editor? The wealth of features is important to me because I want to use it as a central "IDE". I've tried Eclipse, but didn't care for it.

Comment: You could of course go with the classics like vim or emacs. But, if you like gedit so much, is there a reason you want to get rid of it? Simply keep using gedit with awesome and be productive.

Comment: Well I cant tell you exactly. It feels wrong to use Gnome-Apps in a different dektop environment :D and I presume there will be some conflicts, like nautilus drawing to desktop.

Comment: No, it's not wrong at all. The aim is to be productive with your applications to get your work done. There's nothing wrong with using kde applications under gnome or gtk applications under awesome. Don't restrict youself to minimal applications just for the sake of it. Sure, there are some quirks, like with nautilus drawing the desktop, but there are simple solutions and most programs behave just fine. My advice: keep using gedit if you're productive with it. If you're not try vim or emacs.

Comment: When it comes to dependencies. Do you prefer the alternative to gedit to have any particular dependencies except for them being less, e.g. is it better if it depends on GTK than QT?

Comment: Also, could you please include in your question what would make an editor fit for awesome?

Comment: @N.N. well I would say less dependencies to a specific desktop. If its ever again the case that I  have to switch the dektop environment (omg gnome), I dont want to learn new apps. The editor should not really fit for awesome. It should fit for me  and be independant of DEs. I will give vim a try.

Comment: Both ViM and Emacs have the advantage of being really wide-spread so learning to use at least one of those is a good idea of its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [Marco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65770/comparable-editor-for-gedit-with-less-dependencies#comment94585_65770) that sticking with gedit makes sense. After all you say that you cannot work without gedit.

However if you are prepared to spend some time learning a new editor and are curious of how an editor can help you even more than most editors I recommend Vim or Emacs as it is possible to be very productive in them, they are very capable and configurable, has helpful communities and they can be used with few dependencies (they may even be pre-installed on many *nix systems). I used to do my work in gedit but two years ago I started to learn Emacs and I now do most of my work in it and I am very happy with it. The problem with Vim and Emacs is that it takes some time to learn them as they are quite unlike many other editors. Initially it may be a good idea to use an editor you know well in parallel to Vim or Emacs so that you can focus on your work when you need to. If you want encouragement and tips for learning Emacs see the section "Learning" in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50919/5701) to a question about learning Emacs.

To answer you question (instead of saying to stay with gedit or recommending a wholly different editor) an alternative to gedit that has fewer dependencies and the features you ask is [Geany](http://www.geany.org/). It is presented as

> a text editor using the GTK2 toolkit with basic features of
>   an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a
>   small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other
>   packages.

When checking out [its dependencies in Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/geany#pdeps) it indded has fewer dependencies than [gedit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/gedit#pdeps). Also it seems to have the other features you mentioned: it can [edit columns](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#column-mode-editing-rectangular-selections), it can syntax highlighting many languages and it has [an interface for building](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#build-menu). Geany also has other features in common with gedit. For example, it has a [snippet manager](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#id55) and a [plugin system](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#plugins).